# Replacing the PRF in PBKDF2 with Keccak

Tags: sha-256, pbkdf-2, sha-3, keccak, pbkdf

I am unable to find a reliable, tested library for a decent password based key derivation function e.g. Scrypt in the programming language I am using, but I have a reliable library for PBKDF2 (which by default uses SHA2-256) and it also allows me to replace the hash function to use Keccak-256 (C=512) instead.

Is there anything *wrong* with swapping SHA2 for Keccak for use in PBKDF2? For example, maybe Keccak is *not* designed for this usage?

Would it be considered a *better* PRF than SHA2?

I understand it's not a memory hard function, so not as effective as Scrypt in slowing down a serious attacker, however I can compensate for that by restricting password length to at least 30 characters and 100,000 or so iterations.

Comment: If there's no reason in particular to avoid using SHA-2, just use SHA-2. SHA-3 is currently intended as a ready alternative in the event that the SHA-2 family of ciphers is broken, but that is not yet the case.

Comment: Well there is a reason to avoid it, it is designed by the NSA.

Comment: Also there's a lot of specialist equipment e.g. ASICs available for purchase that can do SHA256 for Bitcoin mining. It seems more likely that a spy agency would have a collection of specialist hardware for PBKDF2-SHA1 or PBKDF2-SHA256 password cracking than PBKDF2-SHA3 because practically no-one is using SHA3 yet.

Comment: ASICs for Bitcoin can't do PBKDF2; they are *highly* specialized to the *exact* Bitcoin operations (i.e. SHA256(SHA256(stuff)), and checking the number of zeroes). NSA design is not a particular weakness of SHA-2; it's an open algorithm that has been subject to *extensive* cryptanalysis, far more than SHA-3 has seen, which would tend to undermine the notion that there's a backdoor. More relevantly, what construction does it use for Keccak? Does it use the standard HMAC construction with Keccak? Is that different from HMAC with SHA-3?

Comment: Keccak is substantially faster in hardware than SHA-256, you would make the function MORE vulnerable to brute force attack

Comment: @cpast It may be an open design in terms of an open specification on *how* to implement it correctly, however it is not open design when you consider the architectural decisions behind the algorithm are not publicly available. E.g. the reasons *why* they do certain things a particular way. That is what is lacking with the NSA designed SHA-1 and SHA-2. With openly designed public algorithms from academia, the author will often give the reasons behind their choice of constants, other algorithm details and often use nothing-up-my-sleeve numbers.

Comment: @cpast, Internally I believe it uses HMAC-Keccak-256 and it is fundamentally no different to SHA3-256 with capacity set at 512 bits.

Comment: @RichieFrame To what hardware are you referring which gives the substantial increase in speed? Any benchmarks as evidence of this?

Comment: @RichieFrame What I'm more concerned about is if Keccak is a better PRF, ie produces better entropy in the derived key than SHA-2. I am countering the speed increases for the attacker by using a longer passphrase. It's not so important for the slowness of the function otherwise I'd insist on Scrypt or spend some time implementing Catena.

Comment: @504811E You can't create entropy with a password hash, and that's not what it's for (entropy can only be preserved, but you can't have more entropy in the output of a deterministic function than in the input). A password hash has to deal with the fact that its only secret (i.r. the password) is extremely low-entropy, which it does by being slow (which slows down brute-force attempts).

Comment: And, to reiterate your earlier point, Keccak is *slower* on general purpose CPUs right now than it is in hardware. A critical component of a slow KDF is to minimize any disadvantage the defender has when compared to an attacker, and Keccak currently is weaker than SHA-2 in that regard. Furthermore, while no professional cryptographer I know of has serious reservations about SHA-2 due to NSA involvement, the point is moot. PBKDF2 is built on HMAC, whose [strongest security proof](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) requires only that the underlying function is a PRF.

Comment: @cpast Understood, but I am postulating that SHA3 may preserve the entropy in the salt and password *better* than SHA2. I.e. you get a stronger derived key in the end, therefore the encryption is stronger.

Comment: @StephenTouset I think you may have a valid point regarding the speed of Keccak vs SHA2, however those speed disadvantages can surely be compensated for by using a longer and stronger password.

Comment: @StephenTouset I understand the wider internet is censored within the NSA and they send out propaganda emails within the agency so you don't really know what is really going. Really it might pay to visit an internet cafe or library, access Tor then read up on [what is really going on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_surveillance_disclosures_%282013%E2%80%93present%29). Look at the scope and breadth of their capabilities.  In particular look at their work in weakening and promoting weak cryptographic standards, and also putting NSA employees on standards committees e.g. IETF, NIST etc.

Comment: If you're convinced SHA-2 is backdoored by the NSA, an assertion for which there is no serious evidence in favor (circumstantial or otherwise) and a decade and a half of cryptanalytic evidence against, why would you expect SHA-3 to be any different? But again, the point is moot. It doesn't matter what compression function you use in PBKDF2 as long as it approximates a PRF, with a strong preference towards compression functions that minimize the performance penalty on general purpose hardware versus specialized hardware.

Comment: @StephenTouset NSA has shown that their only goal is to make crypto as weak as possible so they can crack it, but also appear strong enough so that the public unwittingly adopts it. If your adversary is the NSA, then why use their likely compromised crypto to defend against them? People who use NSA crypto and try to claim they are safe *from* the NSA have a significant lack of understanding in game theory.

Comment: @StephenTouset Let's hypothesize that SHA2 has a built in weakness by the NSA (algorithm designers have the advantage to add backdoors) and it's only discoverable if you have a multi-billion dollar supercomputer and dedicate it to finding collisions in SHA2. Maybe the hash outputs result in a finite set of only 2^50 possible hash digests no matter the input. This weakness is obfuscated in the algorithm and the only way to discover it is to have the CPU and storage that the NSA do. Then they promote the use of SHA2 to derive cryptographic keys etc. Now almost all crypto is vulnerable.

Comment: [Not quite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#NSA.27s_involvement_in_the_design), but that's beside the point. Again, SHA-2 and SHA-3 are both NIST protocols. Please explain why you believe that one of them is backdoored by the NSA while the other one remains free of NSA involvement. Additionally, explain how this invalidates the fact that we have an actual mathematical security proof of the HMAC construct used by PBKDF2 under the sole assumption that the compression function chosen is a PRF. Collision resistance *is not a necessary property* under the HMAC security proof.

Comment: From the [proof's abstract](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html): "This paper proves that HMAC is a PRF under the sole assumption that the compression function is a PRF... it also helps explain the resistance-to-attack that HMAC has shown even when implemented with hash functions whose (weak) collision resistance is compromised. We also show that an even weaker-than-PRF condition on the compression function... suffices to establish HMAC is a secure MAC as long as the hash function meets the very weak requirement of being computationally almost universal."

Answer (score 6):

> Is there anything wrong with swapping SHA2 for Keccak for use in PBKDF2?

There are 2 main issues. Performance and implementation.

**Performance**

The performance issue is from an attacker-defender scenario, where the attacker is able to provide FPGA or ASIC resources. In this scenario, Keccak is several times faster than SHA-2. I will use a Blake comparison for SHA-256, as they perform similarly. Both Blake and SHA-2 are ARX type hash functions.

[STM 90nm ASIC](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round2/Aug2010/documents/papers/MATSUO_SHA-3_Criteria_Hardware_revised.pdf)
Keccak-256 = 33333 Mbit/s @ 51 Kgates, Blake-256 = 4763 Mbit/s @ 37K gates, a 7X performance advantage with a 37% area disadvantage, 5.1X overall advantage

[UMC 90nm ASIC](http://www.iis.ee.ethz.ch/~sha3/ethz_gmu_sha3.pdf)
Keccak-256 = 43011 Mbit/s @ 50 Kgates, Blake-256 = 6966 Mbit/s @ 47.5K gates, a 6.17X performance advantage with a 5% area disadvantage, 5.86X overall advantage

[Xilinx Virtex 5 FPGA](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/445.pdf)
Keccak-256 = 12817 Mbit/s @ 1272 slices, Blake-256 = 2245 Mbit/s @ 1523 slices, a 5.7X performance advantage with a 20% area advantage, 6.83X overall advantage

It can be seen an attacker with hardware resources has a performance advantage of 6 times on average vs Blake. In software, Keccak can average half the speed of SHA-512 at the same security level, and can be faster vs SHA-256. This is dependent on the message size, as the block sizes are not the same.

Newer processors will also contain additional instructions to improve the performance of SHA-256 hashing, the level of improvement is yet to be determined.

**Implementation**

The main implementation issue is centered around the design and purpose of HMAC.

HMAC is designed specifically for MD type hash functions like SHA and MD5. Its purpose is to change the initial values to something other than those in the specification. MD type hashes work like a block cipher, with the message the key, and the initial values the plaintext. The ciphertext is then the hash digest. With longer messages, the cipher works in OFB mode, with a key change. The final ciphertext block is then the hash. HMAC works by cycling $[key \oplus ipad]$ for 1 iteration to get a new secret IV, then it processes the message. The output is then processed as the new message using $[key \oplus opad]$ to generate a different secret IV.

Keccak is not an MD type hash function, so the entire purpose of HMAC is lost. Keccak works using the sponge construction with a large internal state. The general rule is to simply prefix the message with the secret key in order to create a keyed hash construction. It is suggested that this would actually be stronger than HMAC because of the large internal state that is kept secret, vs HMAC where an attacker can see the entire state unless there is truncation.

Using Keccak in an HMAC construction is of course possible, but will be much slower than key prefixing, and may not have a security advantage.

The other implementation issue is with code size. On 32-bit systems, SHA-256 will have a massive advantage over Keccak, since blitsliced Keccak is larger and more complex. On 64-bit systems, SHA-512 is a better fit, and Keccak in native 64-bit code is quite compact. The fact that the round constants can be derived at runtime is an advantage, but is usually only used when small code is required, such as an RFID card.

**NSA**

I hesitated putting this section here, but since the comments on the question are a hot topic, I figured it would be pertinent.

Just because the NSA designed something, does not mean it is bad, or secretly backdoored. The NSA is not some super boogeyman, the employees are human beings, and their computers need to obey the laws of thermodynamics. They can not easily sneak something by the cryptographic community. Almost everyone suspected Dual_EC_DRBG was tainted, and advised against its use, even before it became a standard. The only reason it got used was either bribery or incompetence.

I know nobody who suspects the same about SHA-2. Additionally, SHA is one of the most widely studied hash families, with decades of analysis by cryptographers all over the world, including the Russians, Chinese, Iranians, etc. It has stood the test of time better than MD5 and RIPEMD. The only exploitable issues are those common to all MD type hash functions, and if used in HMAC they are mostly irrelevant. SHA-2 is used by the US government to protect state secrets from its enemies, confidently.

If you want to use PBKDF and still don't trust the cryptographic community's view on SHA-2 and all the public analysis for whatever reason, use Blake-512 instead. It has far inferior attacker advantage numbers, excellent software performance, and well analyzed security. I am a fan of truncating the output, I would only keep 256 to 320-bits.

> I am postulating that SHA3 may preserve the entropy in the salt and password *better* than SHA2

Not enough to compensate for the performance advantage of an attacker, if that is even the case..

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing PBKDF2 is still required as the only approved password hashing algorithm if your client receives U.S. government funding or is subject to HIPAA/HITECH Act compliance. It is irrelevant if any other system is better if you can't use it and hope to get paid.

Comment: I suspect that a careful reading of the relevant documents will show that PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA3 is implicitly approved.